# Add acceptor and run it without reboot broker

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have embedded Artemis broker version 2.16.0.

Is there a way to add an `acceptor` and run it without having to reboot the broker?

For example, it is possible to create a `queue` or `address` in `ActiveMQServerControl`.

Or maybe I can add it to the `broker.xml` and then restart some services and the `acceptor` starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add an acceptor to an embedded broker at runtime and start it. Use something like this:

```java
ActiveMQServer server;
...
server.getRemotingService().createAcceptor("myAcceptor", "tcp://127.0.0.1:61617").start();
```

It is possible to add/change certain things in `broker.xml` at runtime but an `acceptor` is not one of them. See [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/config-reload.html) for more details on that.

Comment: It turns out that the acceptor created in this way is not saved when the broker is restarted. Can I make it persist? I also need to write it to the configuration file `broker.xml` along with adding it via a `RemotingService`?

Comment: Most runtime changes to the broker's configuration are *volatile* (i.e. they disappear when the broker is restarted with a new or "fresh" configuration). Typically in embedded use-cases the same programmatic configuration is done every time the broker is created/started. If you want the configuration change to happen at runtime and also be persistent then you'll need to add it to `broker.xml` as well as calling the methods outlined in my answer.

Comment: I added the acceptor in `broker.xml` as well as calling the methods, it is in the config file, but after restarting embedded broker (`EmbeddedActiveMQ embedded.stop()` and `embedded.start()` ), this acceptor does not start and is absent when call `server.getRemotingService().getAcceptors()`. It appears only after a complete reboot of the entire Java application. Why is this happening, how to fix it?

Comment: Invoking `stop()` and then `start()` on `EmbeddedActiveMQ` will not force a reload of the `broker.xml` from disk. You'd have to invoke `setConfiguration(null)` in between `stop()` and `start()`. Also, adding the acceptor to the remoting service doesn't change the underlying configuration object used when starting the broker.